# Java remove public key header and footer from string

Tags: java, android, regex, string, pem

Hi I am trying to remove the header and footer off a public key that is being stored as a string. I have managed to work out how to remove the "begin" header by removing everything up to the first "\n",

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n
```

with this code.

```
String s1 = pKey.substring(pKey.indexOf("\n")+1);
```

I am however struggling to remove the footer from the end up to the last "\n".

```
\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

There must be a cleaner way to remove them both.

Comment: Why? Java contains decoders for this format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
String s1 = pKey.replaceAll("^.*\n|\n-+END PUBLIC KEY-+$", "");
```

**Regex details**

- `^.*\n` - start of string and the first line with a newline
- `|`  - or
- `\n-+END PUBLIC KEY-+$` - a newline char followed with 1+ `-` chars, then `END PUBLIC KEY` and then one or more hyphens till the end of the string.

Answer (score 4):

Public key can be Some thing like this `"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----\nkey\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"`

So to remove header and footer from string you can use
`pKey.substring(pKey.indexOf("\n")+1, pKey.lastIndexOf("\n"));`

or other way just replace header and footer directly by empty , since it won't be present in key

Answer (score 4):

I've been using the following util method to parse RSA public keys from text:

```java
public static RSAPublicKey parsePKCS8PublicKey(String publicKey) {
    publicKey = publicKey
            .replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----", "")
            .replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "")
            .replace("\n", "")
            .trim();
    byte[] bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(publicKey);
    X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(bytes);
    try {
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        return (RSAPublicKey) keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    }
}
```